# VBA - Recursively search through folders and count values within the files found

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to create is some VBA that will recursively go through a set of folders (Folder structure and files can change from time to time) and from each file list them without the extension. Then for each file (They are essentially checklists) count of the amount of "Y" in a range (D6:H25) which would then land we with a count of 60/100 for example. So I would hopefully end up with a spreadsheet like the below.

```
DAVE
80

BEN
12
```

The code that I currently have kind of manages listing all the file names and without the extension.

```
Sub Retrieve_File_listing()
Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Activate
Call Enlist_Directories("<FILEPATH>", 1)
End Sub

Public Sub Enlist_Directories(Filepath As String, lngSheet As Long)
Dim strFldrList() As String
Dim lngArrayMax, x As Long

lngArrayMax = 0
Filename = Dir(Filepath & "*.*", 23)
While Filename <> ""
  If Filename <> "." And Filename <> ".." Then
If (GetAttr(Filepath & Filename) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
  lngArrayMax = lngArrayMax + 1
  ReDim Preserve strFldrList(lngArrayMax)
  strFldrList(lngArrayMax) = Filepath & Filename & "\"
Else

Filename = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(Filename)
ActiveCell.Value = Filename
Worksheets(lngSheet).Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 2, 1).Activate

  End If
 End If
 Filename = Dir()

Wend
If lngArrayMax <> 0 Then
   For x = 1 To lngArrayMax
    Call Enlist_Directories(strFldrList(x), lngSheet)
Next
End If
End Sub
```

I've not managed how to do the count in VBA within the loop, I've done the following within an Excel formula and it gets exactly what I need however doesn't really work within how I want to make this into as minimal effort as possible in the future with little manual intervention.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('<FILEPATH>[DAVE.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$6:$H$25="Y")+ 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Does the code need to loop through subfolders also?

Comment: Yes, so within the directory that I stated as <FILEPATH> there is sub folders within these sub folders are where the files are located where I would have DAVE.xlsx for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, it uses CMD.exe to fetch a list of file names (which is quicker than recursion with `Dir()` ) and evaluates the `SUMPRODUCT` formula using the file information:

```
Sub MM()

Const parentFolder  As String = "C:\Users\JoeBloggs\desktop\" '// NOTE trailing "\" is required
Dim i               As Long
Dim justFile        As String
Dim filePath        As String
Dim fileExt         As String

i = 1

For Each file In Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

    justFile = Left(Mid$(file, InStrRev(file, "\") + 1), InStrRev(Mid$(file, InStrRev(file, "\") + 1), ".") - 1)
    filePath = Left$(file, InStrRev(file, "\"))
    fileExt = Mid$(file, InStrRev(file, "."))

    Cells(i, 1).value = justFile
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(('" & filePath & "[" & justFile & fileExt & "]!Sheet1'$D$6:$H$25=""Y"")+0)"
    Cells(i + 1, 1).value = Cells(i + 1, 1).value

    i = i + 2

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it seems to work great apart from it doesn't populate with the values its just got the standard excel #VALUE, putting the path into a MsgBox (MsgBox (filePath & justFile & fileExt)) and copying that into Windows Explorer opens the file fine without any issues so that's all good. Checked The sheet reference in correct and all is good.

Comment: @Sam it might be that the formula needs to be actually calculated by the application to create the link - see edited code above, if you're still getting the error you can step through and check the formula as it gets entered.

Comment: Noob question incoming! How do I go about doing that specifically I've stepped threw watching the locals (everything looks good) and created a watch on "Formula" and "Cells" however Formula shows <Expression not defined in context> and Cells brings up an extremely long list of stuff and I don't have a clue what I'm looking for there :/ I suspect I'm doing this completely wrong, please could you point me in the right direction for this. The new code brings up this error - Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Comment out the line `Cells(i + 1, 1).value = Cells(i + 1, 1).value
` and run the code, then see what's in the cells where the formula should be. (For debugging tips you can have a read of [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) )

Comment: So I've commented out that bit of code it brings up the same Application-Defined error above. By "see what's in the cells where the formula should be" are you meaning the cells within Excel? If so that's blank now. I'm assuming you are probably referring to Cells within the VBA if so I'm still confused by that. However I saw this error : XPath : <The specified range is invalid due to one or more of the following reasons:

•The range refers to cells in more than one column.
•The range contains mapped cells from more than one XML. Not sure if this is of any relevance at all

Comment: All I've done is use the formula in your original post and put that in a cell _(I was talking about the cells in the actual spreadsheet, not VBA)_ , if it's returning an error then it's a problem with the formula/target workbook

Comment: After all that comparing the formula you sent across the this bit ]!Sheet1' was off as I've changed that to ]Sheet'! and it works!. Thanks for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help yesterday it works great, however one question I have is how would I exclude hidden files for when a user has the spread sheet open and you get the file name preceded with ~$

Comment: Change `/S /B /A:-D` to `/S /B /A:-D-H`